# for loop not running in python

Tags: python, file-io, for-loop

I am writing a program that reads data from a NumPy array (train_data) and uses the scikit-learn RandomForestClassifier to predict results for a column in another file (testing). All of my code works fine except for the for loop at the end of my code that says to take the rows from the testing file and write them in an external file (opening) with an additional column[0] with 0s or 1s depending on the data wont run. Any clue as to why? Here is the relevant code

```
"""------------------Setting up the files-----------------------"""
testing = csv.reader(open('file_name', 'rb'))
header = testing.next()
opening = csv.writer(open('new_file_name', 'wb'))
"""------------------Setting up the files-----------------------"""


"""----------training and predicting--------------------"""
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
Forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100)
Forest = Forest.fit(train_data[0::,1::],train_data[0::,0])
Output = Forest.predict(test_data) 
"""----------training and predicting--------------------"""


"""------Writing new file-------------"""
final_count = 0
for row in testing:
    row.insert(0,Output[final_count])
    opening.writerow(row)
    final_count += 1
"""------Writing new file-------------"""
```

I know for a fact that it's the for loop because I added an additional thing in it that would print "Hello World" if final_count was less than 5 and it never printed. It's not an indentation error because that would come up, so anybody know what could be happening?

Comment: Can you simplify the program to reproduce the error without scikit-learn? You might get better answers without such a heavy dependency, which may not be related to the error at all. Also, have you tried just printing `Output` prior to writing to the file?

Comment: Are you logging uncaught exceptions somewhere?

Comment: @larsmans I have tried running Output and it works fine! And yes it still wont work if I don't require scikit-learn. It's not calling an error though, it just wont run the for-loop

Comment: What is `len(Output)`?

Comment: 418...The same length as the array for test_data, which comes from testing

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: as said before, I am not getting an error, the for-loop is just not running, so it wont write the csv file I need

Comment: How does `test_data` "come from `testing`"? You're not showing how that variable is assigned.

Comment: basically test_data is all of the rows from testing put into a NumPy array so that the .predict() can work. That way the info in Output is for the data in testing so when I add column[0], it is the correct prediction

Comment: When you iterate over the rows of `testing` to make the NumPy array, you are incrementing the iterator forward. By the time you are at the bottom of the script, there are no more "rows" left in the `testing` iterator. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: You were right, I just needed to read the file again right before I ran the for loop and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments above, it was revealed that the OP was using iteration through `testing` to populate a NumPy array. This iteration would advance the `csv` iterator forward in the file, and once it hits the end, the syntax `for row in testing:` will no longer do anything (that is, the iterator has come to the end of the file and so there are no more rows to iterate on).

One fix would be to first iterate through all of the rows of `testing` at the beginning of the program and save all the data into a list or something. Perhaps even wrapping the `csv.reader` with `list()` will work (I am not too familiar with `csv.reader` vs. regular generators / iterators).

Another fix would be to just re-create `testing` again by instantiating the `csv.reader` object once more just before the final loop.

Comment: The file is complete because I use it in a NumPy array (test_data) in order to get it to work with the RandomForestClassifier. So it wouldn't make sense for that to be an issue